# How do I get only my own options within a laravel artisan command?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

Doing a `$this->options()` inside an artisan Command gives me all existing options **every** artisan command has:

```
array (9) [
    'debug' => boolean true <---------- from me
    'help' => boolean false
    'quiet' => boolean false
    'verbose' => boolean false
    'version' => boolean false
    'ansi' => boolean false
    'no-ansi' => boolean false
    'no-interaction' => boolean false
    'env' => null
]
```

but I only want to get my own, in this example: "*debug*".
is there any method or trick I can use here?

why do I need that?
I want a unique hash of my artisan "signature" with all options and parameters. if laravel changes anything in the future within its default options, my hash will change, even I don´t have changed any options, that´s bad.

Comment: to be clear: i know howto get "any" option: `$this->option('debug')` - but i am searching for a way doing this by code, something like `$this->optionsWithoutLaravelOptions()`

Answer (score 6):

After searching deep inside laravel, I am now able to answer myself:

```
$CommandOptions = $this->options();
$LaravelDefaultOptions = $this->getApplication()->getDefinition()->getOptions();
$onlyMyOptions = array_diff_key($CommandOptions,$LaravelDefaultOptions);
dump($onlyMyOptions);
```